# WP Query with multiple taxonomies returns 0 results

Tags: php, wordpress

The aim is to return 3 posts from 2 separate taxonomies.

| Taxonmies | Post 1 | Post 2 | Post 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ld_lesson_category | low-seated | low-seated | low-seated |
| ld_lesson_tag | week1 | week2 | week3-test |

My query:

```
$weeks = new \WP_Query([

    //Weeks post type
    'post_type' => 'sfwd-lessons',
    'tax_query' => [
        'relation' => 'AND',

        //Intensity Level Category
        [
            'taxonomy' => 'ld_lesson_category',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => ['low-seated']
        ],

        //Week nos tags
        [
            'taxonomy' => 'ld_lesson_tag',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => ['week1', 'week2', 'week2-test'],
            'operator' => 'IN'
        ]
    ]

]);
```

If I remove the tax query, all posts are returned. With the tax_query, no posts. It should return 3 posts.

[image: WP Admin View of the posts Im looking to return]

Comment: Does Post 1 having low-seated AND week1 selected ? since your relation is AND . Also use $weeks->request; to debug your sql . After you added these taxonomies did you flush your permalinks ?

Comment: @Snuffy Ive added the image of the admin so you can see the 3 posts that should be returned including the terms applied to them. The "Low" term has the slug "low-seated". Ive dumped the $weeks var and SQL looks ok. Would you like me to add it to the question?

Comment: Did you try `'relation' => 'OR'` in place of `'relation' => 'AND'`?

Answer (score 0):

A similar question has been answered here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/96338/multiple-relationship-for-multiple-tax-query-in-wp-query

Also check that your slugs are actually as you expect.